# How to randomly choose N unique preambles by K number of devices at once with no repitition

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have some problems to be implemented in malab. I have N (number of preambles) to be chosen by K (number of devices). How to randomly choose N by K number of devices, so it is possible one preambles chosen by more than one devices?
for example there are 10 unique preambles (N=10) to be randomly chosen by 50 devices (K=50), just in one time with no repetition and each K devices only can choose one from 10 unique preamble by random. I would like to know from those 10 unique preambles, how many are chosen by exactly one devices only and which preambles? and how many preambles are chosen by more than one devices and which preambles?
How to implement this scenario in matlab? I really need your response ASAP. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your preambles (whatever that is in your application) are here:

```
preambles = [12 13 14];
K = 6;
```

then generate a vector of random indices into `preambles`, like this:

```
random_indices = 1 + floor(rand(1, K) * length(preambles));
```

which you can then plug into the `preambles` variable:

```
preambles(random_indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
r = randperm(N*K); % generate a random permutation of the integers from 1 through N*K
r = mod(r(1:N:(K-1)*N+1), N); % the random selection results
[uniques,numUnique] = count_unique(r); % the selected preambles (uniques), and how many times they were selected (numUnique)
```

The `count_unique` function can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23333-determine-and-count-unique-values-of-an-array)